# How to use a different symbol for each point in a list plot?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I am using `ListPlot`to show the relationship between a list of x/y pairs that occurred every six months over a twelve year period. Instead of plotting with dots, as shown below, I would like to plot with the dates (e.g. Jun99) when the observations occurred. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[100, {25, 2}];
markers = DateString[#, {"MonthNameShort", "YearShort"}] & /@ 
   DateRange["June 1990", "June 2002", {6, "Month"}];

ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotMarkers -> markers, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

You can use the `{marker,size}` form to control the marker sizes:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotMarkers -> Thread[{markers, 16}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, phooey. I tried this approach. I must have made a syntactical error (which I looked for but didn't find).

Comment: Actually, I didn't try your approach. On first reading, I missed that `List/@data` isn't an ordinary list plot, but instead is a plot of many lists of length one. That is what makes it work. Very clever!

Comment: I just looked at your profile. Plotting guru.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPlot[Labeled[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{3, , DateString[]}, {5, 
    DateString[]}, {9, DateString[]}, {16, DateString[]}, {22, 
    DateString[]}}]
```